# is loading various subviews when I enter to a view controller better than loading one by one when required?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with 3 subviews and 3 buttons, the buttons tell me which subview show, but when entering to the vc takes too much time, it's better and faster to create and load each subview when the buttons is pressed? or how can i improve this situation?

edit: each view has an image a text field and a text view, i have seen that most people have problems with big images

Comment: It takes a virtually no time to create three views.  Something else must be the problem

Comment: Pull up Instruments, run the Time Profiler, and see where the problem is. I agree with @danh, if it's just "three views and three buttons" there is no way that, by itself, is the problem.

Comment: Make sure you add these controls and subviews from the main thread. You can get weird delays or other problems if you do UI updates from a background thread. If that's not it, create a [small example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you solve it.

Comment: hi guys, i'm really new at swift so i really don't know too much about what is the main thread but i will search about that.
I was thinking that maybe i can build the views programmatically but i'm not sure that this could improve the execution time